# How to create class for json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a class for this this type of json data

```
"Fields": {
    "{C7D1DDA4-897B-4947-9BC3-074B5D416878}": {
      "Name": "subject",
      "Type": "Single-Line Text",
      "Value": "Entry/Withdrawal Confirmation"
    },
    "{430A7D54-F67C-444E-A888-6898E6D454A8}": {
      "Name": "body",
      "Type": "Multi-Line Text",
      "Value": "You have entered $tournament with $playerName at $Location"
    }
  }
```

Comment: you really need a class or you want to work with the json settings? is http://www.newtonsoft.com/json not a solution?

Comment: i really need a class problem with this C7D1DDA4-897B-4947-9BC3-074B5D416878 i am not able to create a class like this i want to access it dynamically

Comment: is it in your hand to change the json format? there where the guid is name it Description and iniside add a property guid?

Answer (score 2):

A very easy method is to use this online converter [website](http://json2csharp.com/) . Just paste the JSON there and it would generate the classes for you. If the  JSON is not valid, the tool would inform

Comment: for this i need to create a classes also like this C7D1DDA4-897B-4947-9BC3-074B5D416878,430A7D54-F67C-444E-A888-6898E6D454A8 but i dont want to do like

Comment: your JSON is invalid it seems. paste the complete JSON there and the website creates classes for you

Comment: i follwed website suggested by you and it result wrong format.The following code generated


public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Item item { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

Comment: That's correct ... so that RootObject will have all values and you need to query it .

Answer (score 0):

above json have key value pair. Whenever this type of json will have then we need to use Dictionary because Dictionary have key value pair. The following will be code for you :

```
public class YourClassName{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Type {get; set;}
   public string Value {get; set;}
}


public returnType YourServiceName(List<Dictionary<Guid, YourClassName>> model){
//your code will be here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard-to-use JSON (or perhaps even invalid, but I'm no expert) in the sense that JSON typically consists of key-value pairs, but all the GUIDs that we see are actually values that are being used as keys.

If you can change the JSON to be more like this, it would be a lot easier to process:

```
{
  "Fields": [
    {
      "id": "{C7D1DDA4-897B-4947-9BC3-074B5D416878}",
      "item": {
        "Name": "subject",
        "Type": "Single-Line Text",
        "Value": "Entry/Withdrawal Confirmation"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "{430A7D54-F67C-444E-A888-6898E6D454A8}",
      "item": {
        "Name": "body",
        "Type": "Multi-Line Text",
        "Value": "You have entered $tournament with $playerName at $Location"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```